# QueryDSL usage with Spring Boot 2.x and higher

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest, querydsl

We have an app that was built on a very old version of Spring Boot (1.3). This app uses Hibernate 4.3.x and QuerDSL 3.x.

The app heavily relied on Spring Boot's support QueryDSL's predicates.. Below is a sample code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/findAll", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public HttpEntity<PagedResources<Resource<OrderEntity>>> findAll(@QuerydslPredicate(root = OrderEntity.class) Predicate predicate,
                                                                         Pageable pageable,
                                                                         PagedResourcesAssembler<OrderEntity> assembler) {
 //return something
}
```

Now, the problem is QueryDSL is not being actively maintained and I would like to avoid using QueryDSL. Can anyone suggest an alternative to QueryDSL that is compatible with newer versions of Hibernate and helps achieve the same dynamic querying as in above code snippet?

Comment: You could use https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications

Comment: Yeah.. Specifications is not as helpful/dynamic as QueryDSL predicates.

Comment: you can go with jooq

Comment: Yes I would also recommend https://www.jooq.org/ for queries.

Comment: It is slowly coming back to life with initial focus on addressing issues with latest Hibernate versions. https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/2459

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at *[CriteriaBuilder](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-and-or-criteria-predicates)* however I believe *Querydsl* is better and is more 'type safe'.